# dynamic buffer size for reading input

Tags: c, dynamic, size, buffer

I am trying to create a program that will read line by line from stdin, search that line for the start and end of a given word and output all the matching words. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char **words = NULL;
    int word_count = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        int length = strlen(buffer);
        if (buffer[length - 1] == '\n') {
            word_count = count_words(buffer, FIRSTCHAR);
            if (word_count > 0) {
                words = get_words(buffer, FIRSTCHAR, LASTCHAR);
                for (int i = 0; i < word_count; ++i) {
                    printf("%s\n", words[i]);
                    free(words[i]);
                }
                free(words);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got the basic functionality working, but I am relying on fgets() with a fixed buffer size.
What I would like is to dynamically allocate a memory buffer with a size based on the length of each line.

I can only see one way of going about solving it, which is to iterate over input with **fgetc** and increment a counter until end of line and use that counter in place of *sizeof(buffer)*, but I don't know how I would get fgetc to read the correct relevant line.

Is there any smart way of solving this?

Comment: Linked list? each struct has `next` field and `char* p`?

Comment: If you are using a POSIX system or compiling with GCC, you can use [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) to get the whole lines. This function allocates the space needed for the whole line.

Comment: @TonyTannous could you please elaborate? I now about linked lists and have considered if I could utilise them, but I'm not sure exactly how

Comment: How long do you think the longest line will be? Take that number, multiply by 10, and `malloc` that much memory. You really don't need to be any more sophisticated than that, unless the longest line is expected to be in the 100s of megabytes.

Comment: If by "smart" you mean simple, one-liner, then no I don't think so. You don't know what data you've got until you read it, simple as that. @Pablo 's suggestion to use `getline` is probably your best option, but I bet if you look under the hood of that function it's looping and `realloc`ing. This sounds a bit like an X-Y problem,, are you expecting lines in the file to be really really long? Sufficiently sized fixed buffer should be fine for many use cases. If not, I might treat it as binary data, read in the whole file (unless it's huge), and do the line parsing myself.

Comment: A POSIX `limits.h` will have this defined:  `LINE_MAX`
*Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file)... Minimum Acceptable Value:* `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX`.   On the systems I have looked at, _POSIX2_LINE_MAX was 2048 and LINE_MAX was 4096.

Answer (score 4):

> but I am relying on `fgets()` with a fixed buffer size. What I would like is to dynamically allocate a memory buffer with a size based on the length of each line

I did wrote a version of `fgets` for another SO answer that reads the whole line and returns a
`malloc` allocated pointer with the contents of the whole line. This is the
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *fgets_long(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t size = 0, currlen = 0;
    char line[1024];
    char *ret = NULL, *tmp;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        int wholeline = 0;
        size_t len = strlen(line);

        if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
        {
            line[len-- - 1] = 0;
            wholeline = 1;
        }

        if(currlen + len >= size)
        {
            // we need more space in the buffer
            size += (sizeof line) - (size ? 1 : 0);
            tmp = realloc(ret, size);
            if(tmp == NULL)
                break; // return all we've got so far
            ret = tmp;
        }

        memcpy(ret + currlen, line, len + 1);
        currlen += len;

        if(wholeline)
            break;
    }

    if(ret)
    {
        tmp = realloc(ret, currlen + 1);
        if(tmp)
            ret = tmp;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The trick is to check if the newline was read. If it was read, then you can
return the buffer, otherwise it reallocates the buffer with `sizeof line` more
bytes and appends it to the buffer. You could use this function if you like.

An alternative would be if you are using a POSIX system and/or are compiling with GNU GCC, then you
can use [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) as well.

```
void foo(FILE *fp)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    if(getline(&line, &len, fp) < 0)
    {
        free(line); // man page says even on failure you should free
        fprintf(stderr, "could not read whole line\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("The whole line is: '%s'\n", line);

    free(line);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function: `getline()` does just what you want.  The syntax:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

The function is exposed in the `stdio.h` header file and usually requires something like:  `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L` or `#define _GNU_SOURCE` as the first line in the file that calls `getline()`

Strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN page for `getline() for all the grubby details.

Comment: Thanks! I am however looking at solving this by making my own functions, to learn C better